# C# P/Invoke not working when passing struct with embedded string to C dll

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have an old C dll that I need to wrap with C# code.  I used the P/Invoke signature tookit to get the following structure definition:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SDRMSG
    {
        public uint Stream;
        public uint Function;
        public uint Wbit;
        public int Length;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string Buffer;
        public int Error;
        public int Next;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string Txtp;
        public int Txtc;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string Wtxtp;
        public int Wtxtc;
    }
```

from the original C definition:

```
typedef struct {
     unsigned int  stream;
     unsigned int  function;
     unsigned int  wbit;
     SDRLENGTH     length;
     unsigned char * buffer;

     SDRLENGTH     error;
     int           next;
     unsigned char * txtp;
     SDRLENGTH     txtc;
     unsigned char * wtxtp;
     SDRLENGTH     wtxtc;
 } SDRMSG;
```

What happens is I need to initialize this structure and send it to a C .dll where the .dll will fill the buffer field with data.  The buffer field in the original C struct was just a pointer to a char array that I initialized in my client code.  Armed with the pointer, the C .dll was able to write directly into the buffer.  I am trying to get the same result with C# code but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get the buffer field initialized correctly so that the C .dll can fill it with data.  It always comes back to my client code empty.  Here is one attempt (among several others that I can't quite recall) that does not seem to work.

```
        secsMessage.Stream = 1;
        secsMessage.Function = 13;
        secsMessage.Wbit = 1;
        secsMessage.Length = 8000;
        secsMessage.Buffer = new string('\0', 8000);
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to initialize the structure so the C .dll can write to the buffer?

Comment: It sounds like you want `byte[]` as the managed type for some of the struct members instead of `string`.  If the data represents a null-terminated array of `char` in C, then you want `string`.  If it's a deterministically-sized buffer that will be filled with data potentially containing embedded zeros, you will want a `byte[]` instead.

Comment: The buffer is not deterministically sized.  I am hard-coding to a specific size here just for simplicity.  I think string is the correct type.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e765dyyy.aspx) example should set you down the right path.

Comment: I actually found that link and tried following the samples provided.  Still doesn't work.  When I write the same code in C++ passing the pointer to the buffer, everything works.  It just seems that no matter what I try with the C# code, the buffer remains empty.  I guess I may have to resort to unmanaged code within my C# application and go back to using pointers.  Not sure how to do that either, though, so need to do some reading.